# How do I calculate the duration that two time periods overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
  Duration = Case
        When ([Start_Datetime] <= [MIN_START]) and [End_Datetime] Between [MIN_START] and [MAX_END] Then [MIN_START] - [End_Datetime]
        When ([Start_Datetime] <= [MIN_START]) and ([MIN_START] and [MAX_END] ) Between ([Start_Datetime] and [End_Datetime]) Then [MAX_END] - [MIN_START]
        When ([Start_Datetime] >= [MAX_END]) and [MAX_END] Between [Start_Datetime] and [End_Datetime] Then [MAX_END] - [Start_Datetime]
        When ([Start_Datetime] >= [MAX_END]) and ([Start_Datetime] and [End_Datetime] ) Between ([MIN_START] and [MAX_END] ) Then [End_Datetime] - [Start_Datetime]
        Else 0                                                           
From DB1


Example [Start_Datetime] [EndTime] [MIN_START][MAX_END] [Result]
    1          1              6         2          7        4 
    2          2              6         3          5        2 
    3          4              7         3          6        2  
    4          3              4         2          7        1
```

I try to use And and Between My SQL error
It said

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'and'.

I just want to know how to correct this thanks

Comment: `([Start_Datetime] <= [MIN_START]) and ([MIN_START] and [MAX_END] ) Between ([Start_Datetime] and [End_Datetime]) Then [MAX_END] - [MIN_START]` this isn't valid. What are you trying to achieve

Comment: `([MIN_START] and [MAX_END] ) Between` makes no sense. You can only check if one field at a time is between something else. You probably need two BETWEEN statements, one for each of these two dates, with an AND in between them.

Comment: Unrelated - your missing an END.

Comment: I am trying  to calculate the overlap duration between 2 Time Range EX: Start Time 4 -10. End Time 3-5. Overlap 1 hour

Comment: `BETWEEN` should not be used with parentheses

Comment: @SQLNOOB- Add sample data and expected result

Comment: This is definitely falling into an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) category. OP, please rephrase your question like "How do I calculate the duration that two time periods overlap". Your attempt has numerous issues and it's difficult to discern what were trying to do from your code alone. If you could also include sample data for your four data fields and your desires results that would further help get a good answer here.

Comment: what is the datatype of your columns? are those integers?

Comment: all is Datetime

Comment: for one, I don't think you can subtract date time like [MIN_START] - [End_Datetime], you should at least use DATEDIFF(HOUR, startdate, enddate)

although this should give you a different error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps when dealing with datetime period intersection problems to break the problem up into scenarios.

In your case we are interested in whether the two periods intersect and, if so, what the duration of intersection is:

```
Period 1 (Min_Start to Min_End)
Period 2 (Start_Datetime to End_Datetime)
```

Scenario1:

```
P1: <----------->
P2:                  <----------->

OR
P1:                  <----------->
P2: <------------>
Du: NULL

WHEN Min_End < Start_Datetime OR Min_Start > End_Datetime THEN NULL

--We can also check the opposite of this (Do these periods intersect?):

WHEN Min_End >= Start_Datetime AND Min_Start <= End_Datetime THEN --THEY INTERSECT!
```

Scenario2:

```
P1: <---------------------------->
P2:      <--------------------------->
Du:      <----------------------->

WHEN Min_Start <= Start_Datetime AND Min_End <= End_DateTime THEN Min_End - Start_Datetime
```

Scenario3:

```
P1: <---------------------------->
P2:    <------------->
Du:    <------------->
WHEN Min_Start <= Start_Datetime and Min_End > End_Datetime THEN End_Datetime - Start_Datetime
```

Scenario4:

```
P1:    <----------------------->
P2: <------------->
Du:    <---------->
WHEN Min_Start > Start_Datetime AND Min_End > End_Datetime THEN End_Datetime - Min_Start
```

Scenario5:

```
P1:    <--------------->
P2: <------------------------->
Du:    <--------------->
When Min_Start > Start_Datetime AND Min_End < End_Datetime Then Min_End - Min_Start
```

This could be written like:

```
CASE 
    /*S1: Do they intersect?*/
    WHEN Min_End >= Start_Datetime AND Min_Start <= End_Datetime 
        THEN                
            CASE 
                /*S2*/ WHEN Min_Start <= Start_Datetime AND Min_End <= End_DateTime THEN DATEDIFF(day, Start_Datetime, Min_End)
                /*S3*/ WHEN Min_Start <= Start_Datetime and Min_End > End_Datetime THEN DATEDIFF(day, Start_Datetime, End_Datetime)
                /*S4*/ WHEN Min_Start > Start_Datetime AND Min_End > End_Datetime THEN DATEDIFF(day, Min_Start, End_Datetime)
                /*S5*/ WHEN Min_Start > Start_Datetime AND Min_End < End_Datetime THEN DATEDIFF(day, Min_Start, Min_End)
                END
    END
```

Hopefully that is correct. These things always confuse the hell out of me ;)

Comment: Sorry for the typo,  i mean max_end.

Comment: `WHEN Cast(T1.[Start_Datetime] AS datetime) = T2.[MAX_END] OR [End_Datetime] = Cast(T2.[MIN_START] AS datetime) THEN 0`   This code is for when time range are back to back

Comment: @SQLNOOB That's good one. I was aiming only for period intersection, and that would be period meeting. Scenario 6 then :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your last condition:

```
 When ([Start_Datetime] >= [MAX_END])
  and ([Start_Datetime] and [End_Datetime] )
 Between ([MIN_START] and [MAX_END] )
        Then [End_Datetime] - [Start_Datetime]
        Else 0
```

What do you want to achieve with `Between ([MIN_START] and [MAX_END] )`

this does not make sense, maybe you meant:

```
When ([Start_Datetime] >= [MAX_END]) 
and ([Start_Datetime] Between [MIN_START] and [MAX_END]) 
and ([End_Datetime] Between [MIN_START] and [MAX_END]) 
Then [End_Datetime] - [Start_Datetime]
```

this is for the last condition

Answer (score 0):

To determine the start/end of the range, you just need to compare the max start date with the min end date. Here's an example with test values matching the ones from the question.

```
DECLARE @duration1_start INT, @duration1_end INT, @duration2_start INT, @duration2_end INT

-- Test 1: Returns 4
SELECT @duration1_start = 1, @duration1_end = 6, @duration2_start = 2, @duration2_end = 7 
-- Test 2: Returns 2
SELECT @duration1_start = 2, @duration1_end = 6, @duration2_start = 3, @duration2_end = 5 
-- Test 3: Returns 2
SELECT @duration1_start = 4, @duration1_end = 7, @duration2_start = 3, @duration2_end = 6 
-- Test 4: Returns 1
SELECT @duration1_start = 3, @duration1_end = 4, @duration2_start = 2, @duration2_end = 7 

SELECT (SELECT MIN(en) FROM (SELECT @duration1_end AS en UNION SELECT @duration2_end)sq) -
(SELECT MAX(st) FROM (SELECT @duration1_start AS st UNION SELECT @duration2_start)sq)
```

Conversely, if you actually want to use datetime fields, you can use this:

```
DECLARE @duration1_start DATETIME, @duration1_end DATETIME, @duration2_start DATETIME, @duration2_end DATETIME

-- Test 1: Returns 4
SELECT @duration1_start = '1/1/2018', @duration1_end = '1/6/2018', @duration2_start = '1/2/2018', @duration2_end = '1/7/2018' 
-- Test 2: Returns 2
SELECT @duration1_start = '1/2/2018', @duration1_end = '1/6/2018', @duration2_start = '1/3/2018', @duration2_end = '1/5/2018' 
-- Test 3: Returns 2
SELECT @duration1_start = '1/4/2018', @duration1_end = '1/7/2018', @duration2_start = '1/3/2018', @duration2_end = '1/6/2018' 
-- Test 4: Returns 1
SELECT @duration1_start = '1/3/2018', @duration1_end = '1/4/2018', @duration2_start = '1/2/2018', @duration2_end = '1/7/2018' 

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, 
(SELECT MAX(st) FROM (SELECT @duration1_start AS st UNION SELECT @duration2_start)sq), 
(SELECT MIN(en) FROM (SELECT @duration1_end AS en UNION SELECT @duration2_end)sq))
```

If there's no intersection, you'll get a negative number, because the max start value is greater than the min end value. You can handle that scenario with a case statement:

```
-- Test 5: Returns -1
SELECT @duration1_start = 3, @duration1_end = 4, @duration2_start = 5, @duration2_end = 6 

SELECT CASE WHEN diff < 0 THEN NULL ELSE diff END
FROM
(
    SELECT (SELECT MIN(en) FROM (SELECT @duration1_end AS en UNION SELECT @duration2_end)sq) -
    (SELECT MAX(st) FROM (SELECT @duration1_start AS st UNION SELECT @duration2_start)sq) AS diff
)sq
```